# How to replace namespace uri with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

How do I replace the namespace uri of one or more elements of an XML message without knowing beforehand the namespace prefix that will be arbitrarily used by the sender?

I know forms of this question have been asked many times, but every answer I find (here and in other sites) presupposes exact knowledge of a prefix.  Prefixes, by definition, are arbitrary, and the solution to this shouldn't require a hardened knowledge of the prefix used.

I have a solution, but it results in junk I do not need in the output.  Simple input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myThing xmlns:s="http://tempuri3.org/">
    <s:thisThing>
        <thatThing xmlns="http://cheapCookies.org/"/>
        <anotherThing xmlns="http://kingkong.org">
            <thisThing/>
        </anotherThing>
    </s:thisThing>
</myThing>
```

This is the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:param name="sourceNamespace" select="'http://tempuri3.org/'" /> 
  <xsl:param name="targetNamespace" select="'http://tempuri.org'"/> 

  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/> 

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="namespace-uri() = $sourceNamespace">
                <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{$targetNamespace}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the Output of the above XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<myThing xmlns:s="http://tempuri3.org/">
    <s:thisThing xmlns:s="http://tempuri.org">
        <thatThing xmlns="http://cheapCookies.org/" xmlns:s="http://tempuri3.org/"/>
        <anotherThing xmlns="http://kingkong.org" xmlns:s="http://tempuri3.org/">
            <thisThing/>
        </anotherThing>
    </s:thisThing>
</myThing>
```

This is the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<myThing xmlns:s="http://tempuri.org/">
    <s:thisThing>
        <thatThing xmlns="http://cheapCookies.org/"/>
        <anotherThing xmlns="http://kingkong.org">
            <thisThing/>
        </anotherThing>
    </s:thisThing>
</myThing>
```

Comment: "*Prefixes, by definition, are arbitrary,*"  Prefixes are arbitrary, namespaces are not. It's not clear from your description whether you know in advance the namespaces/s used in the source.

Comment: I do know the source and target namespace uris, but I won't know the prefix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I do know the source and target namespace uris,

Then you should probably do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:old="http://tempuri3.org/"
exclude-result-prefixes="old">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="old:*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://tempuri.org">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result may vary slightly according to the exact processor used. For example, Saxon 6.5 will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myThing xmlns:s="http://tempuri3.org/">
  <thisThing xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
    <thatThing xmlns="http://cheapCookies.org/"/>
    <anotherThing xmlns="http://kingkong.org">
      <thisThing/>
    </anotherThing>
  </thisThing>
</myThing>
```

Comment: Very nice!  local-name().... it didn't immediately occur to me that I didn't need the prefix on the output.

Comment: You could also use `name()` function but from the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl:element): *XSLT processors may make use of the prefix of the QName specified in the name attribute when selecting the prefix used for outputting the created element as XML; **however, they are not required to do so**.*